# Webpack Error React & ES6 Previously working under Babelify

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I Have tried to move from babelify, watchify, browserify to webpack, webpack server and babel.

I remember 6 months ago moving away from webpack because it gave me similar issues trying to use the aws-sdk.

For some reason, every time I build I get the following error:

> Hash: 396f0bfb9d565b6f60f0 Version: webpack 1.14.0 Time: 61ms    [0]
>   ./src/index.js 0 bytes [built] [failed]
>
> ERROR in ./src/index.js Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\src\index.js Unexpected token (9:8) You
>   may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token (9:8)
>       at Parser.pp$4.raise (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
>       at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1822:12)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprList (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2165:22)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseSubscripts (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1741:35)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1718:17)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1573:21)
>       at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:727:47)
>       at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:638:25)
>       at Parser.parse (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:516:17)
>       at Object.parse (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:3098:39)
>       at Parser.parse (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\lib\Parser.js:902:15)
>       at DependenciesBlock. (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:104:16)
>       at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
>       at nextLoader (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
>       at C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
>       at Storage.finished (C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
>       at C:\Users\james\Documents\hyre\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)

I Believe I have everything set up as required.
Please see my files:

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/js',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hyre",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.4.4",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "is-my-date-valid": "^0.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-date-picker": "^5.3.26",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.28.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "transform-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
/*let message = 'Loaded----->';
console.log(message);*/

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/app';

render (<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mistake in **webpack** config. `resolve`, `module` and `loaders` properties should not be nested inside of `output` prop, they should be at the same level. Here is valid config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/js',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: True, but no luck.

Comment: The same error? Have you relaunched wepback? Just a watch-reload would not be enough.

Comment: Yeah same error. I'm manually building at the moment while I set up.

Comment: Try to remove `cacheDirectory` option

Comment: No luck unfortunately.

Comment: I had this as my previous working hack in my package json: >"start": "watchify src/index.js -v -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] -o public/js/main.js"

Comment: But that was just to bypass webpack, if that helps.

Comment: I'll take a look later. Now have to go.

Comment: Change your presets order to `['es2015', 'react']`. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392826/webpack-and-react-unexpected-token?rq=1