# Reactjs "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" while npm start

Tags: reactjs, react-router, babeljs, babel-loader

The react app that I have is an old code and I am trying to build my react app with the following command to complete the setup of the project.

```
npm run-script build
```

Here is the configuration in package.json

```
"webpack": "^3.12.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.5"
"babel-core": "^5.8.20",
"babel-loader": "^5.3.2",
```

and my node and npm versions are

```
node 10.15.3 
npm v6.4.1
```

my routes.js looks like

```
module.exports = (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path='list' component={Roadshows} />
  </Router>
)
```

I tried installing different versions of webpack, webpack-dev-server and babel-loader.

```
/home/local/TAG/vigneshs/project/react/roadshow/roadshow_frontend/routes.js:62
  <Router history={history}>
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

When I try to start my server using

```
npm start
```

I getting the same error.

can anyone please do guide to complete the setup of the project. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The Error is clearly shouting that there is something wrong in `routes.js` line 62. and also clearly says the error is an unexpected token. what was the reason that you have not checked that file?

Comment: I have checked that file, but the syntax is correct. I have updated the routes.js file also. The error isn't that character. There is some package version mismatch.

Comment: are you using the babel preset for react?

Comment: this may be similar to--or a duplicate of: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392826/webpack-and-react-unexpected-token

Comment: @worc, Yes I do. I use presets --> babel-preset-es2015 & babel-preset-react and I use the following in .babelrc
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}

Answer (score 2):

You should not using `module.exports` to export component. Try following:

```
export default () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path='list' component={Roadshows} />
  </Router>
);
```

and then, import it

```
import routes from 'routes'
```

Comment: When I do this, I m getting --> SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Comment: @Vicky that's progress, makes me wonder if the `npm start` command isn't using babel correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by reducing versions of my webpack and webpack-dev-server as,

```
webpack v1.10.5
webpack-dev-server v1.10.1
```

and also I used lower version of node and npm

```
node v8.15.1
npm v6.4.1
```

I guess the issue I had was -->  webpack@3 and webpack-dev-serve@2 which I used earlier didnot support babel-loader@5